# VHDL subtraction calculation

Tags: vhdl

How does VHDL do a subtraction calculation? Does it do the two's complement? 
For a 2bit subtractor, I was showed to use vectors for i/o but it would require 3 input pins/switches to be able to test the out. (Downloading to DE0 Nano Board).
So I tried to use the integer values:

```
entity TwoBitSubtractor is port(
    x,y         : in integer range 0 to 3;
    result     : out integer range -3 to 3);
end TwoBitSubtractor;

architecture gates of TwoBitSubtractor is
begin
    result <= x - y;
 end gates;
```

It compiled successfully but some of the outputs in the board confuses me.
For example:
01 - 10 = 100

Here is a ss of the DE0 nano board

[image]

For a -1 wouldn't it be a 111 instead?

DE0 nanoboard specs
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu737/tidu737.pdf

Comment: I cannot recreate your case, with my [simulation](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4sVV) the result is always proper, the problem might be the connection with board is somewhat breaking the logic in some way? I am not familiar with DE0 Nano Board at all, can you share its specifications, documentations etc?

Comment: Can I see the output circuit on the DE0?

Comment: Ok, I synthesized with Quartus II and run the netlist and the result is correct: https://imgur.com/a/lR0mPJX . Could you post your netlist file here?

Comment: Can you try to use signed values? Use that to pass `001` & `010`, and expect `111`, I am thinking this is due to `integer` use. Otherwise it is an extremely simple entity =)

Comment: you shall post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to understand where the conversion is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating with `integer` signals, but you can set IO pins only with type `std_logic` or a bunch of them using `std_logic_vector`. So somewhere in your top entity, which you haven't shown us, there's a conversion between `integer` and `std_logic(_vector)`. There is no implicit functionality, you have to cast to `signed` or `unsigned` datatype, look here([Duolos VHDL designer guide](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/numeric_std/)) for conversion functions.

I guess you are using `unsigned` values, try to use `signed` in Top level entity. Same is for the inputs, you can't specify an `integer` with `"01"` or `"10"`, only with literals like 0, 1, 2, 3.